# Was the Rancor handler able to go into the enclosure unprotected?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, rancor

In Return of the Jedi we are shown the [rancor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rancor) for the first time which was a pet of Jabba the Hut.

> Rancors were large **semi-sentient** reptilian carnivores native to the
>   planet Dathomir.[8] Standing around five meters tall,[1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rancor) with their
>   long arms, immense jaws, and armored hides that could withstand
>   blaster fire, they were formidable predators.

We are shown when Luke is dropped into the enclosure and is  trapped but, he manages to kill it. After that the rancor handler burst his way through and is visibly upset.

What I want to know is, was he able to interact with the beast and have it show affection or some other pet like interaction or was this like humans keeping wild lions, and unable to interact with them?

Was the rancor handler able to go into the enclosure unprotected?

Answer (score 7):

### Probably

The rancor keeper does not view the rancor as a dangerous beast to be contained, but as a friend, something to be “cherished.”

> Jabba the Hutt’s drooling rancor may love gobbling up Gamorrean guards
> (armor and all), but the deadly beast is cherished by his keeper,
> Malakili.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*</sub>

The beast is also described as his “pet”:

> A giant shirtless man rushes in: the rancor keeper. Instead of
> attacking Luke, however, he runs straight for the rancor.
>
> And as a
> crowd of guards surrounds Luke, the rancor keeper weeps for his lost
> pet.
>
> <sub>*Beware the Power of the Dark Side!*</sub>

Further, Malakili is described as being one of the only people who can “tame” rancors. Presumably a prerequisite for taming rancors is making them not eat one on sight.

> The purpose of the man, Malakili, was once to give purpose to such
> creatures. He was always good with beasts. As a child in a Nar Shaddaa
> slum, **he taught vicious gugverms to stop stealing from the food
> stores—and over time they became his pets, his friends, his
> protectors.** Later, he would help tame and prepare a variety of beasts
> for the Hutt circuses: sand dragons and kill-wings and little womp
> rats in their little outfits. **And then later, his precious joy, the
> rancors. Those, the monsters none could tame but he.**
>
> <sub>*Aftermath: Life Debt*</sub>

His taming of the rancor is described in the same paragraph as him turning vicious animals into his protectors, so I think we can assume that he and the rancor had a relationship that was at least not that of predator and prey.

Comment: There is more in Tales from Jabbas Palace